# Is it worth partitioning a Table by single value in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

Normally, if you have a column you frequently query a table by, you ought to stick an index on it. But is it worth also partitioning a table by this column, if all possible values are known in advance? Let's say you have a table `AUDIT` with `TenantId` column which could only containt values: *1, 2*. 
**All** `SELECT` statements would have a `WHERE` clause with a `TenantId` parameter.

So, would it be beneficial to [partition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c12parti.htm) this table by TenantId? If so, would you also create an index on `TenantId` column?

```
partition by list (TENANTID)
(
  partition TENANT1 values (1),
  partition TENANT2 values (2)
)
```

I have done a little experiment: inserted 1M records with TenantId randomly generated, thus creating:

- 499652 records with TenantId=1
- 500348 records with TenantId=2

Here are the query plans for statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE TENANTID=2
```

**Plain Table (no indices, no partitions)**
[image: Plain Table Query Plan]
**Bitmap Index:**
[image: Bitmap Index query plan]
**Partitions:**
[image: Partition query plan]

Btw, in case where I have both, the index and partitions, query plan uses partition and not index, hence the plan looks exactly the same as the 2nd one shown above.

Clearly the partition wins, *but does it?* 
Apparently, [the cost column in an execution plan is not a reliable way to judge the real costs of a SQL statements response time](http://dba-oracle.com/t_sql_execution_plan_cost_column.htm).

So, what is the best way then? How to choose one over another?

Comment: I've updated my answer to respond to your update.

Answer (score 5):

My opinion is that partitioning of that table in the manner presented **may** be useful.

Your queries will be two times faster (in the case when partitions are almost equal) if they make full scans.

In case your queryes have another tone of filters/conditions and use indexes, partitioning is not useful, because the level of an index is almost not affected by doubling the number of values.

**UPDATE**: For the test you did (`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE TENANTID=2`) it is sure that partitioning is best. The bitmap solution need to scan the index, and after this, to scan all table's blocks containing rows with `tenantid=2`(it knows what are the rows). But partitioning will cause just scanning the table's partition with tenantid=2. They are phisically separated to `tenantid=1`.

So, two scans(index scan + table scan) vs one table scan(wich may be smaller).

Answer (score 3):

When a column contains few distinct values, a.k.a. low cardinality, as in your case, you should create a Bitmap index on it. When you frequently query by that column, that is.

Here's more about Oracle Bitmap Indexes:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_bitmapped_indexes.htm

Comment: Thanks, I've done a little test here with 1M rows: 500348 with TENANTID=2, 499652 with TENANTID=1 randomly distributed and, according to the QUERY PLAN, partitioned table has smaller cost (1112 vs 1521) compared to bitmap indexed one. How would you explain it?

Comment: Can you post your query here.

Comment: see the edit please

Comment: A bitmap index might not be a good choice if the table is being updated frequently (and concurrently)

Comment: @Tsar, I see that you have concluded that the Cost column that you had been looking at turned out to be unreliable, so I guess I don't have to explain anything to you anymore about rowids.

Comment: A **single** bitmap-index on a table usually does not bring much gain. Typical use case for bitmap indexes is when you have several indexes and the query uses a combination of them.

Answer (score 0):

It can be very useful on a column with unevenly distributed data.

For example you have column `status` with values `ACTIVE` and `HISTORY`. The `HISTORY` partition might be much bigger but much less frequently queried than the `AVTIVE` partition.